# How to use variables in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, cordova

Created the following code in SQL however need to use it in sqlite (phonegap specifically).

```
INSERT INTO actions(Action) VALUES ('Go to the pub');
SET @aid = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO statements(statement, Language) VALUES ('Have a pint', 'English');
SET @sid = LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO Relationships(SID,AID) VALUES (@sid,@aid);
```

The issue we are having however is how to declare the variables in sqlite.

The LAST_INSERT_ID() will become last_insert_rowid(), however what is the sqlite version of SET @aid = ?

Answer (score 1):

SQLite does not have variables.

In an embedded database such as SQLite, there is no separate server machine or even process, so it would not make sense to add a programming language to the DB engine when the same control flow and processing logic could be just as well done in the application itself.

Just use three separate `INSERT` statements.
(In WebSQL, the result object has the `insertId` property.)